# AngularJs ng-dirty flag being applied

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

In our rather complex form I found that the ng-dirty flag being applied when nothing was actually changed. I originally thought the problem was in the placeholder attribute on the input text, but now even with this attribute removed the flag is still being set when nothing was changed. Is it some sort of a bug? If yes, what is the solution? The problematic elements defined as following

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-show="isNew">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-lg-3" title="@Labels.operatorCode">@Labels.operatorCode:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" name="opCode" id="opCode" ng-model="currentOperator.opCode"
                               class="form-control" ng-maxlength="6" ng-show="isNew"
                               ng-required ="isNew" />
                        <div class="field-validation-error" >
                            <span ng-show="form.editOperatorGeneralForm.opCode.$error.required && form.editOperatorGeneralForm.opCode.$dirty">@String.Format(Messages.isRequired, Labels.operatorCode)</span>                        
                            <span ng-show="form.editOperatorGeneralForm.opCode.$error.maxlength && form.editOperatorGeneralForm.opCode.$dirty">@String.Format(Messages.cannotExceed, Labels.operatorCode, "6")</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The form itself is quite complex with several tabs.

I only see this problem in Chrome browser now, it works fine in IE (no question).

Comment: Can you check to see if any code is focusing or bluring the field using ngBlur and ngFocus with a console log?

Comment: Can you please clarify this suggestion? Also, how would I know what causes the event to fire if it fires?

Comment: I meant to just add the two directives `ng-focus="test()"` and ng-blur="test()"` to the form field.  In the controller set `$scope.test = function (event) { console.log(event); }`

Comment: I also just found that this problem only shows up when I run it from my local developer's machine. Running the same form in QA doesn't produce that problem

Comment: Nothing shows up in console, e.g. these 2 events are not firing. And I can understand that as the controls are not even visible.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not answer your exact question, I do believe it will solve your problem.  Consider doing your validation logic like this.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':!SomeForm.someValue.$valid && SomeForm.$submitted}">
    <label class="control-label" for="someValue">Some Value</label>
    <input id="someValue"
           name="someValue"
           class="form-control"
           type="text"
           placeholder="(Required)"
           required
           ng-model="vm.temp.someValue"
           ng-maxlength="255"/>
    <div class="help-block" 
            ng-messages="SomeForm.someValue.$error"
            ng-if="SomeForm.$submitted">
        <div ng-messages-include="ui/messages.tpl.html"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
vm.submit = function(Form, data) {
    if (!Form || Form.$invalid) { return; }
    if (vm.isUnchanged()) { return; }
    someService.save(data).then(function () {
        Form.$setPristine();
    });
};
```